# PHP MYSQL compare time with created in database

Tags: php, mysql

I want to check if 30 min passed after `created` time in database. `created` is a time column having time stamp in this format `1374766406`

I have tried to check with `date('m-d-y H:i, $created)` but than of course it is giving human readable output so don't know how to perform check if current time is not reached to 30min of `created` time.

Something like `if(created > 30){}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
$created = // get value of column by mysql and save it here.

if ($created >= strtotime("-30 minutes")) {
    // its over 30 minutes old
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Let me try. just for understanding, why `-30` ?

Comment: to have the timestamp representation of "30 minutes ago"

Comment: strtotime($created) not giving any output. null/blank. Any idea?

Comment: Try to remove `strtotime()` around it.

Comment: no effect.. :( just for info, I am getting value for the created time is `1374766406`

Comment: It is not working. Is there anything with the format? the result giving me value as mentioned in above comment but in database it is `2013-10-10 15:25`

Comment: So is your `$created = '2013-10-10 15:25'`? Or `$created = '1374766406'`?

Comment: When I am getting into the system the value I am getting is `11374766406` but in database as I said

Comment: So are you trying to find out if timestamp from db is passed 30 mins? Or opposite?

Comment: I am trying in both way but something going wrong.. not working and when I checked time in human readable format using date() for `created` and current time than found weird the `time()` is lesser than `created` Now is that the issue with the xampp timezone and my machine timezone issue?

Comment: I noticed weird things like you too. I think xampp timezone is not accurate. Use `date_default_timezone_set` to set timezone corresponding times in your database. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php

Comment: Okay I think that was the issue with the timezone in xampp and my machine. It seems working fine now. Just a question.. Than what if I upload this to the server and someone will use it from different timezone?

Comment: You could detect user's timezone and then set timezone according to user's location.

Comment: @aksu thanks a lot for your help. Your code defiantly works now but I had to select Abhik answer. I appreciate your and everyone's help.

Answer (score 1):

The better approach is to use DateTime for (PHP 5 >= 5.3.0)

```
$datenow = new DateTime();
$datenow->getTimestamp();

$datedb = new DateTime();
$datedb->setTimestamp(1374766406);

$interval = $datenow->diff($datedb);
$minutes = $interval->format('%i');
```

$minutes will give you the difference in minutes, check here for more

https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php

Here is the working code

http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/jxv-eyg

Comment: It's giving something big errors. Let me rewrite the code

Comment: I see your code outputting the minute value, but again how to compare it?

Comment: that value is the difference and u can use to any predefined value like if($minutes > 30) or something to perform some operation.

Comment: oh i see. let me try this too

Comment: Okay cool this is working fine.. Now just confused what is the best approach in all these?

Comment: Well start using the DateTime since strtotime() has a date range limitations. Check in google :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use strtotime(); to convert the date in human form back to a timestamp, then you can compare.

EDIT: Maybe I misread.

So something like;

```
if(($epoch_from_db - time()) >= 1800){
    //do something
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You mean first convert `created` with date() than take time and add 30min and convert back to `strtotime()` and again compare with original `created` is that right what I understood?

Comment: If the time is stored as a timestamp, you might aswell just subtract it from the current time, using the time() function, which will leave a positive integer, then see if that is over 1800 seconds (30 minutes).

Comment: This method is easy but considering time in wrong way. Does `time()` consider computer time or the server

Comment: "computer time or the server"? The server is a computer. I assumed they were the same machine. If not they should both have their timezones set the same if they're to interact. You'd never run a database server on a different timezone than PHP.

Comment: Yes I understand that just to know if it is the server or the client machine time.

Comment: It's the machine the function is run on. You can override/set it with ini_set('date.timezone', 'America/Los_Angeles'); To set it to the same as your server if need be.